# Modifiable Areal Unit Problem

Tags: correlation, descriptive-statistics

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifiable_areal_unit_problem)

> The modifiable areal unit problem (MAUP) is a source of statistical bias that can significantly impact the results of statistical hypothesis tests. MAUP affects results when point-based measures of spatial phenomena are aggregated into districts, for example, population density.

**The scale effect** showing major analytical differences depending on the size of units (generally correlations more pronounced for bigger units)

**The zonation effect** showing major differences depending on how the study area is divided up, even at depending on how the study area is divided up.

I have a dataset for workers in Denmark and I am considering the relation between experience and high skill occupations. Experience is measured as years of full time activity on labour market and is treated as a continuous variable. High skill occupation is binary. Aggregation to group level is done by taking group means. The groups are defined by the 98 municipalities covering Denmark.

Using aggregate measures experience and high skill occupation is negatively correlated.

However when not aggregated the correlation is positive, as I would have expected.

Is there an intuitive explanation for this perhaps related to the MAUP problem?

Comment: Sure sounds like Simpson's Paradox.

Comment: Yes perhaps I get it let me try: So ranking areas according to mean level of experience the share of workers in high skill occupation is decreasing. While within each area higher level of experience is postively correlated with being in a high skill occupation. Not sure what could explaing it though, perhaps explained by workers with age (and growing experience) moving to the suburbs and taking a job there where high skill occupations are less frequent (but that is offcourse another story). My areas are basically one city center and areas around that. Not many cities in Denmark.